# Property setter not called for databound property

Tags: c#, data-binding

I got a Combobox bound to a custom object. Most of the time the following code does not set the custom object (but from times to times it does). Do you have any clue on the issue?

```
// In the main form
_person = new Person();
_citySelector.DataBindings.Add("SelectedCity", _person, "Adress.City"); //Adress is an object, city too

// A property of _citySelector (city selector derives from UserControl and implements INotifyPropertyChanged )

public City SelectedCity 
{
  get { return ultraComboCities.SelectedRow.ListObject as City;}
  set
  {
    // Horrible but there is no selector.SelectedValue = 
    foreach (UltraGridRow row in ultraComboCities.Rows)
    {
       if(row.ListObject as City == value)
       {
          ultraComboTiers.SelectedRow = row;
          RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCity");
          return;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

// I call the following code on my city select object 
// (1)
SelectedTier = City.Get("London"); //ultraComboCities was first populated with cities object including London

After the call of (1), `_person.Adress.City` is (most of the time) not refreshed.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Does the _citySelector's SelectionChanged event handler set the SelectedCity method? 2. does Person implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: 1-You means, when (1) is called, does the raise event is called ? If so, the answer is yes and PropertyChanged changed event contains one method called-------------2-No, I only need a "one way binding", do Personn need to implement it ?